# Resize a button depends the Smartphone

Tags: jquery, css, html, button, resize

How can i resize a button depends on the smartphone? 
I want to set the button on the middle of the screen.

If a smartphone with a smaller display use the app, so the app should change the size of the button. 
Using jquery, html5, css

Comment: [Media Queries](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=media+queries&oq=media+queries&gs_l=hp.1.0.0l10.37.27114.0.27935.9.8.0.1.1.0.122.782.5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.32.hp..1.8.700.3SvCFrC5Lg8)

Comment: @DanDascalescu this question haves nothing to do with the one you marked as duplicated.